# xPlore throwing java.lang.SecurityException: Continuous Random Number Generation Check failed in index logs

Tags: java, documentum

**[DM_INDEX_AGENT_PLUGIN]** Document represented by key `r_object_id` failed to index into **repository**, `error:java.lang.SecurityException: Continuous Random Number Generation Check failed`

The index agent is throwing above exception while indexing the object.Got the following stack trace in logs. So what could be the possible resolution for this?

`at com.rsa.jcm.f.jc.g(Unknown Source)
        at com.rsa.jcm.f.jg.h(Unknown Source)
        at com.rsa.jcm.f.cp.i(Unknown Source)
        at com.rsa.jcm.f.cp.nextBytes(Unknown Source)
        at com.rsa.jcm.f.cp.nextBytes(Unknown Source)
        at com.rsa.cryptoj.o.b.engineNextBytes(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(SecureRandom.java:455)
        at java.util.UUID.randomUUID(UUID.java:145)
        at com.emc.documentum.core.fulltext.common.RequestIdGenerator.getId(RequestIdGenerator.java:25)
        at com.emc.documentum.core.fulltext.indexserver.core.index.ESSIndexServer.createIndexResponse(ESSIndexServer.java:401)
        at com.emc.documentum.core.fulltext.indexserver.core.index.ESSIndexServer.update(ESSIndexServer.java:136)
        at com.emc.documentum.core.fulltext.indexserver.core.handlers.impl.BatchIndexRequest.handleRequestBody(BatchIndexRequest.java:39)
        at com.emc.documentum.core.fulltext.indexserver.core.handlers.impl.AbstractRequestHandler.handle(AbstractRequestHandler.java:26)
        at com.emc.documentum.core.fulltext.webapp.FtDispatchFilter.execute(FtDispatchFilter.java:164)
        at com.emc.documentum.core.fulltext.webapp.FtDispatchFilter.doFilter(FtDispatchFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
        at com.emc.documentum.indexserver.rest.log.MessageLoggingFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)`

Comment: is this happening after you make something or just starting the service?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't expected to get this kind of question here. Normally, professional tech support from EMC should be able to answer that.
Technically, this error indicates there is something wrong in the JVM which is running Documentum xPlore. 
Please check the log files under xPlore jboss folder, like dsearch.log, xdb.log, server.log.
The error itself indicates the underlying JVM failed to generate qualified UUID using specified cryptography algorithm, which is absolutely abnormal.

Wish it helps you.

By the way, for more Documentum xPlore issue, you can try to find answers from http://community.emc.com or raise SR to http://support.emc.com

Sheperd